# Peoplecode TRANSFER to page without search record

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

Is there a way to use the PeopleCode "transfer" function to transfer (and fill in fields) to a page where the component uses INSTALLATION as the search record?

We are using FSCM 9.1 on PT 8.53.

The page I'm trying to transfer to is AP_VOUCHER_INQUIRY
The menu path is: Accounts Payable -> Review Accounts Payable Info -> Vouchers -> Voucher

I have the business_unit and the voucher_id that I need to pass to it. Inside of the Activate PeopleCode for the page, I see this:

```
  /*  If Business Unit and Voucher ID are being passed to this page, this code picks it out and populates the From/To fields and executes the search statement.  This code allows another page to use the TRANSFER function passing "some_record.BUSINESS_UNIT" and "some_record.VOUCHER_ID" as keys while opening Voucher Inquiry in a new browser.  */
 &bu = Unencode(%Request.GetParameter("BUSINESS_UNIT"));
 &vchr_id = Unencode(%Request.GetParameter("VOUCHER_ID"));
 &vchr_style_inq = Unencode(%Request.GetParameter("VOUCHER_STYLE_INQ"));
 &vndr_setid = Unencode(%Request.GetParameter("VENDOR_SETID"));
```

Comment: Check out the code in PYMNT_VCHR_DET.GBL.DERIVED_AP.VOUCHER_ID_LBL.FieldChange to see how the delivered code is doing this.  They use a %response.RedirectURL

Comment: Thanks Darryls99 - that worked perfectly.  I will update with an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Darryls99, I found a way to do this:

```
 &url = GenerateComponentContentURL(%Portal, %Node, MenuName."ENTER_VOUCHER_INFORMATION", %Market, Component."AP_VCHR_INQ", Page."AP_VOUCHER_INQUIRY", "U");
 %Response.RedirectURL(&url | "&BUSINESS_UNIT=" | "BUPO" | "&VOUCHER_ID=" | &row.USM_ACTEXP_WRK2.VOUCHER_ID.value);
```